# Populate Excel VBA Combo-box with Column Headers

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I want to populate a combobox with the column headers (A1 through AR1)
How do I do that in Excel VBA?

Comment: It is possible to populate combobox with 2D array values by putting it in `Combobox.List`, it excludes loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should do the trick:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Range("A1:AR1")
    Data_UF.CB.AddItem (Cell.Value)
Next Cell  
End Sub
```

What its doing is: Loop through each cell from A1 to AR1, Add it to the Combobox (CB) thats in the Userform (Data_UF).
This is being done at the time of initialization.